# Assembly output was displayed on a new line, despite no line feeds

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, x86-64, nasm

I was writing a basic assembly program in nasm, linux, that asks for the users name and should output "Hello (name) it is very nice to meet you". However the "it is very nice to meet you" is displayed on a completely new line, not after the name like I intended.

Here is the code:

```
global _start

section .text

_start:
        MOV rax, 0x01   ;Writes "What is your name?"
        MOV rdi, 0x01
        MOV rsi, name
        MOV rdx, nameL
        SYSCALL

        MOV rax, 0x00   ;Reads input
        MOV rdi, 0x00
        MOV rsi, name_V
        MOV rdx, 16
        SYSCALL

        MOV rax, 0x01   ;Writes "Hello "
        MOV rdi, 0x01
        MOV rsi, hello
        MOV rdx, helloL
        SYSCALL

        MOV rax, 0x01   ;Writes name value after "Hello "
        MOV rdi, 0x01
        MOV rsi, name_V
        MOV rdx, 16
        SYSCALL

        MOV rax, 0x01   ;Writes greeting after name value
        MOV rdi, 0x01
        MOV rsi, greeting
        MOV rdx, greetingL
        SYSCALL

        MOV rax, 0x3C   ;Exits program
        MOV rdi, 0x00
        SYSCALL

section .data
name: DB "What is your name? "  ;0xA = LINE FEED
        nameL: EQU $ - name     ;get length
        hello: DB "Hello ",
        helloL: EQU $ - hello   ;get length
        greeting: DB " it is very nice to meet you"
        greetingL: EQU $ - greeting     ;get length

section .bss
        name_V: resb 16 ;reserves 16 bytes for user input
```

I can't see any reason why it would display on a new line.

[This is the output from the terminal:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYOXl.png)

Comment: That's because the user pressed enter (producing a linefeed character on linux) and you are reading that and printing it out. Also you are printing 16 bytes irrespective of how many the user typed which is a bad idea. A possible oversimplified solution could be to `push rax` after the input then `pop rdx; dec rdx` (instead of using constant 16) for printing.

Comment: Ohhh that’s obvious now, any way to avoid that though, or any better ways of doing it in the first place?

Comment: @dungeonphoenix Search for the newline character in the user input and overwrite it with a NUL byte.

Comment: @fuz how would I go about searching the input for the character and then replacing it? Not got much experience with assembly

Comment: @dungeonphoenix Go through the buffer character by character and compare each with a newline character.  If you find a newline character, overwrite it.

Comment: Since the newline will be at the end, you can just chop off the last byte as I showed (you can check if you want). That of course won't work if the user enters more than 15 characters or if you feed it multiple lines in one go.

Comment: @fuz: They're using `write(int fd, void*buf, size_t len)` for output, which uses explicit-length buffers not 0-terminated C strings.  So you overwriting a `0xa` with a `0x0` isn't really what you want.  On a terminal it's a zero-width character, but it's more correct not to output that byte at all, by decrementing the length you got from a `read` return value.  (As you've often pointed out, a simple and robust way is to use libc stdio functions like `call fgets` to read a whole line up to some buffer-size limit, even if that takes multiple `read` system calls, e.g. from a pipe.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I intentionally made this choice as it is easier than removing the character completely from the buffer (e.g. by moving the characters behind it forwards).

Comment: @fuz: I'm always going to remember the first-year undergrad CS assignment where I thought it was pretty cool that I could `printf("foo%c", count > 1 ? 's' : '\0');` to pluralize something with just a character, not a whole string, obviously more efficient :P.  Or something like that.  Looked correct on my terminal, but the automated grading script stopped looking at the rest of my program's output.  Because presumably it was using a tool that used C strings internally, perhaps bash `foo=$(program)` or maybe a C program, and my program's output included a terminator.